# How do you limit the number of decimal places in the output of multiple numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I've recently started learning Python and have made a simple program to calculate the area of a circle, however, I don't like the output of the answer and wanted to know how it would be possible to limit the number of decimal places in the output for multiple variables.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
rad = input("Insert the radius of your circle: ")
radius = float(rad)
area = np.pi*(radius**2)
per=2*np.pi*radius

print("The area and perimeter of your chosen circle of radius "+str(radius)+" are: "+str(area)+" and "+str(per)+" respectively")
```

Output I get:

```
Insert the radius of your circle: 56.3

The area and perimeter of your chosen circle of radius 56.3 are: 9957.87481815703 and 353.7433327942107 respectively
```

Output I would like:

```
Insert the radius of your circle: 56.3

The area and perimeter of your chosen circle of radius 56.3 are: 9957.87 and 353.74 respectively
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use f-strings

- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498: Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
- no need to use `+`
- no need to convert the `type`
- set the number of decimal places shown, with `:.0xf`, where `x` is the number of places to the right of the decimal, that will be shown.

### Your last line should be:

```py
print(f'The area and perimeter of your chosen circle of radius {radius:.03f} are: {area:.03f} and {per:.03f} respectively')
```

#### Output from you code with new f-string:

```py
Insert the radius of your circle:  6
The area and perimeter of your chosen circle of radius 6.000 are: 113.097 and 37.699 respectively
```